# Ansible subelements (version 2.3)

Tags: arrays, ansible

How to get such a structure?
My code doesn't work

```
user:
  - username: test1
    home: /home/test1
    outbox: Outbox
    inbox: Inbox
    subfolders:
      - _test1
      - _test2
      - _test3
```

test1
-------test1_test1
----------- Inbox
----------- Outbox
-------test1_test2
----------- Inbox
----------- Outbox
-------test1_test3
----------- Inbox
----------- Outbox

```
- name: Creating sub-folders
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.0.home }}/{{ item.0.username }}{{ item.0.subfolders }}/{{ item.0.inbox }}"
    mode: 0775
    owner: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    group: "{{ web_user }}"
    state: directory
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user }}"
    - subfolders
  when: subfolders is defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will come in handy :)

```
  file: 
    path: "{{ item.0.home }}/{{ item.0.username }}{{ item.1 }}/{{ item.0.inbox }}"
    mode: 0775
    owner: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    group: "{{ web_user }}"
    state: directory
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ user }}"
    - subfolders
```